# missing } inserted, Displaying aligned matrix equations, yet braces balanced

Tags: math-mode, align, matrices

I am trying to display in math mode two system equations aligned

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{shortstack}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{minipage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % math fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}    % font definition
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}



\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\title{ wrthuywetshsdfghdsgh }
\author{ 2po4ihu524 }
\begin{document}
\maketitle  

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
{
    % State Equations
    X^{(c)}_{t + 1} &= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    {
        \gamma  & 1-\gamma & 1\\
        0       & 1        & 0\\
        0       & 0        & \zeta
    }
    \end{bmatrix}
    X_t + 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    {
        0 \\
        0 \\
        b_3
    }
    \end{bmatrix}
    U_t + { ^{x}Q^{(c)} }^{1/2} { ^{x}eps^{(c)}_t } \\
    % "Observation equation" 
    X^{(c)}_{t+1} &= \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} X_t +  { ^{y}Q^{(c)} }^{1/2} { ^{y}eps^{(c)}_t }        
}    
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

and I get the error is here:

```
(...)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\marvosym\marvosym.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings\listings.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings\lstmisc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings\listings.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\booktabs\booktabs.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hdvips.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pdfmark.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\lmodern.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\carlisle\slashed.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\subfig\subfig.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty")

Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.

))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [9pt].

No file dumb.aux.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\ot1lmr.fd")
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omllmm.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omslmsy.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lm\omxlmex.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.64 \end{align}
```

?

The parenthesis & braces are balanced. What is the problem?

Comment: Your first and second `bmatrix` constructions include inner `{`...`}`'s, while your last set of `bmatrix` constructions don't. Remove the entire inner `{`...`}`. The same goes for the groups defined as part of `align`.

Comment: remember that alignment cells are groups just looking at the first `{
    % State Equations
    X^{(c)}_{t + 1} &`  it clearly has an unmatched `{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there is a brace `}` down by `\end{align}`

Comment: @user27886: That's not the problem; it's that you're unnecessarily opening up a group that TeX expects to not be there after the first cell `&`.

Comment: For future reference, when providing the community with a minimal example, make sure that it's minimal. That is, remove all unrelated content (like making titles, or loading [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) *twice*, or using an unused `9pt` document class option, or...).

Comment: Ah. Fair enough.

Comment: @user27886 that close brace is not relevant as it is in a different scope. each table cell has to have matching brace groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are unnecessarily grouping interior content inside the `align` and `bmatrix` environments. Remove those inner groups which are causing the mismatched brace groups:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    % State Equations
    X^{(c)}_{t + 1} &= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \gamma  & 1-\gamma & 1\\
        0       & 1        & 0\\
        0       & 0        & \zeta
    \end{bmatrix}
    X_t + 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        b_3
    \end{bmatrix}
    U_t + { ^{x}Q^{(c)} }^{1/2} { ^{x}\text{eps}^{(c)}_t } \\
    % "Observation equation" 
    X^{(c)}_{t+1} &= \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} X_t +  { ^{y}Q^{(c)} }^{1/2} { ^{y}\text{eps}^{(c)}_t }
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that it's typeset, I clearly have to clean up my notation a bit.

Comment: not only "unnecessarily", but also "incorrectly".  although it's a basic principle of latex that an environment by definition forms a closed group, the fact that most `amsmath` environments perform operations that incorporate `&` to subdivide the content into "cells" means that extra braces used in this way will cause problems.  i suppose it wouldn't hurt to mention that in the `amsmath` documentation.  i'll add that to the list, but can't promise when it might happen.  (this is also true for `eqnarray`, for the same reason.)